# Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for (data)

Tags: javascript, angular

According to this link : https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

I'm trying to inject data from Component to other and then trying to append `<dynamic-component [componentData]="data"></dynamic-component>`

First Component

```
componentData = any;

//Calling API

if (success)
{
    this.componentData = {
       component: NewsFeedComponent,
       inputs: {
       new_data: this.result
               },
    };

}
```

Second Component

```
constructor( private injector: Injector) {

        this.data = this.injector.get('new_data');

    }
```

And then I use my dynamic Component as the link above said. But I got this error
[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Aravind I'm trying to append dynamic Component after passing specific data from component to other. check [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxd8fn?embed=1&file=app/helloworld/helloworld.component.ts)